# Unity delegate conversion issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delegates, event-listener

I'm encountering a problem on Unity :

I try to make an event listener with delegate, and I took the code from tutorials but I've a bug when I try to add the delegate method into an other class method : "Cannot implicitly convert type `void' to`Metronome.OnTickEvent".

Here is my class with the delegate :

```
public delegate void OnTickEvent();
public event OnTickEvent onTick;

IEnumerator coroutineMetronome() {
    if (CustomTimer.manager.timerState) {
        for (;;) {
            nextTick += delay;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(nextTick - Time.time);

            onTick(); // I call the delegate method here 
        }
    }
}
```

... and that is the event receiver class :

```
protected virtual void Start ()
{
    manager = this as T;

    Metronome.manager.onTick += OnSynchronization(); // Here is the bug line
}

protected void OnSynchronization() {
    Debug.Log("coucou");
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need parenthesis after the method name:

```
Metronome.manager.onTick += OnSynchronization;
```

With the parenthesis it would mean that you want to call the method first, then add the result to the event.

The corrected code is a short version of

```
Metronome.manager.onTick += new OnTickEvent(OnSynchronization);
```

Comment: Damn I didn't see it. Thank you